# How to set content of a parent selection tag in Tinymce Wordpress editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I need to select an image in wordpress visual editor to edit its url in a shortcode dialog window. It work fine and the img url is replaced as well:

```
var content = editor.selection.getContent();
content = content.replace(original_url, new_url);
editor.selection.setContent(content);
```

But my problem is to replace also the parent selected image `<a href>` attribute with the `new_url` value.

The `editor.selection.getContent()` function return only the img tag:

```
<img class="wp-image-1007 size-medium" src="**original_url**" width="373" height="250" />
```

and not:

```
<a href="**original_url**" target="_blank">
<img class="wp-image-1007 size-medium" src="**original_url**" width="373" height="250" />
</a>
```

With jQuery i could do:

```
var imgsel = editor.selection.getNode();
jQuery(imgsel).parent("a").attr("href", new_url);
```

but inside the editor doesn't works.
How can i replace the image link url using editor.selection.setContent() function?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , use selection.getNode();

```
var img = editor.selection.getNode();
img.setAttribute('src' , newURL);
var parent  = editor.dom.getParent(img,'a');
parent.setAttribute('href' ,newURL);
```

Comment: Thank you @m.kerkeni for answer. 
`parent.setAttribute('href' ,newURL);` return the correct new url but href, on tinymce dialog closing, is not updated with the new url.

Comment: What's the output of editor.getContent() before closing tinymce dialog?

Comment: `<p><a href="original_url"><img class="alignnone wp-image-1007 size-medium" src="new_url" alt="" width="373" height="250" /></a></p>`